# Recursive Javascript: child->parent relationship

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to walk a chain of parent->child relationships until we reach a parent that does not have its own parent. If the child has a parent, then we store that parent object in the array along with any parents of that parent. If the parent doesn't have a parent, we store an empty array.

Here's some pseudo-JSON showing the data-structure I want.

```
Node3 = { // Node 3
   parent: { // Node 2
      parent: { // Node 1
         parent: null,
         parentTree: []
      },
      parentTree: [Node1]
   },
   parentTree: [Node2, Node1]
}
```

Here is the constructor function and the recursive method so far...

```
function Node(parent) {
    this.parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : null;
}

Node.prototype.getParentTree = function() {
    if(typeof this.parentTree === "undefined") {
        if (this.parent !== null) {
            this.parentTree = this.parent.getParentTree();
            this.parentTree.push(this.parent);
        } else {
            this.parentTree = [];
        }
    }
    return this.parentTree;
}
```

Here is how I'm testing the method:

```
var node1 = new Node();
var node2 = new Node(node1);
var node3 = new Node(node2);

node3.getParentTree();
```

The problem with the current method is that the parentTree for node1, node2, and node3 all have length === 2. When you inspect the objects in parentTree they contains pairs of sub-objects to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> this.parentTree = this.parent.getParentTree();
> this.parentTree.push(this.parent);
> ```

That way, both the parent's and child's `parentTree` refer to the very same Array object - so you're appending the new node to the parent's tree as well.

Create a copy of the array by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
return this.parentTree.slice(); // every time the getter is called
```

or

```
this.parentTree = this.parent.getParentTree().slice(); // only for manipulating
```

Comment: Worked great and I now see where my problem was. Thank you!